# What does " 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first_name' mean in this situation?

Tags: python

I'm getting an error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first_name' with the below code. I'm completly stuck

```py
class User:
    """Summarizes User Profile"""
    def __init__(self,first_name, last_name, followers, following):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.followers = followers
        self.following = following
        self.fullname = first_name + " " + last_name

    def describe_user(self):

         print(self.fullname + " has " + followers + " and follows " + following + " users")

    def greet_user(self):
        """Greets user"""
        print("Welcome back, " + self.fullname)

#User info
user1 = ("Krish","Patel",100, 200)
user2 = ("Bob","Smith",2032, 153)

User.describe_user(user1)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'first name'

Comment: Your User1 and User2 are just tuples. i.e. of the form (a, b, c, d). You want to do User(a, b, c, d).

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually instantiate a `User` object not just a `tuple`. Try

```
user1 = User("Krish","Patel",100, 200)
user2 = User("Bob","Smith",2032, 153)
```

Comment: I don't understand, could you please be more specific

Comment: And instead of `User.describe_user(user1)` OP should use `user1.describe_user()`. (A better name for that method might just be `describe()` since it's on the `User` class, making the association clear).

Comment: @KrishPatel, carefully compare Kent's code to your code where you create `user1` and `user2`.

Comment: Now it says          no attribute 'describe_user'

Comment: OH GOD, I'm so dumb, I can't unsee that, thank you so much

Comment: @KrishPatel I recommend taking a look at the Python docs on [how to instantiate a class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).